# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused select count(*) as aggregate from `admins` where ( `username` = admin and `password` = admin )

Tags: php, laravel

/ 
Http
 / 
Controllers
 / 
AdminController
.php
 
: 24

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Models\Admin;

class AdminController extends Controller

{

```
//Dashboard

public function index(){

    return view('index');

}

 //login

 public function login(){

    return view('login');

}

 //Submit_login

 public function submit_login(Request $request){

     $request->validate([

         'username'=>'required',

         'password'=>'required'

 ]);

 $checkAdmin=Admin::where(['username'=>$request->username,'password'=>$request->password])->count();

 if($checkAdmin>0){

     return redirect('admin');

 }



 }
```

}

Comment: And your problem is..........?

Comment: Please format your question properly and state what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You can not check passwords directly from the database because of password hashing.

You should try:

```
$checkAdmin = AdminUser::where('username',$request->username)->first();

if (Hash::check($request->password, $checkAdmin->password)) {
    return redirect('admin');
}
```